# Huffman code - compression

Tags: algorithm

I've heard about something like a compression factor, or just simply compression, according to the huffman coding topic. I remember the formula:

```
compression = ( Linput - Loutput ) / Linput
```

However, that's all I know and I can't find any even smallest piece of information about that formula.

If you've seen this, what does that mean? What are those Linput and Loutput variables? What is the compression here?

Not to be lazy I've found that compression has something to do with making huffman trees in different ways, so I can get different codeword lengths for the letters. But that's actually all I know.

EDIT. Sorry, I tagged it as c++ by mistake. Old habits die hard :P

Comment: [wikipedia?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding)

Comment: The formula is for compression algorithms in general, not just Huffman coding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linput and Loutput are the Lengths of the input and output data. The formula you gave calculates the effectiveness of a compression method, by dividing the difference between the lengths by the original length.

Example: when you reduce a string of 100 bytes to 80 bytes, the compression factor is `(100-80)/100` = `20/100` = 0.2, where higher numbers are better.

Comment: Thanks, but specifically to the huffman code - input string contains plain letters, but output string is a binary code - how do I compare this?

Comment: @user2252786: Both "plain letters" and "binary code" use a certain amount of bytes. You just have to determine the size of the input (in bytes) and the size of the output (still in bytes) and then apply the formula.